# Why can procs be invoked with === in ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, proc-object

[This article](http://www.igvita.com/2011/02/03/new-ruby-19-features-tips-tricks/) mentions 4 ways to invoke procs in ruby 1.9, and === is one of them. I don't understand why this would be done this way at all. Does it have any relationship to the normal meaning of === (asking if the two objects are the same object)?

```
irb(main):010:0> f =-> n {[:hello, n]}
=> #
irb(main):011:0> f.call(:hello)
=> [:hello, :hello]
irb(main):012:0> f === :hello
=> [:hello, :hello]
irb(main):013:0> Object.new === Object.new
=> false
irb(main):014:0> f === f
=> [:hello, #]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is what the docs have to say](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Proc%3a===):

> It is to allow a proc object to be a target of `when` clause in the
>   case statement.

This is a, perhaps contrived, example:

```
even = proc { |x| x % 2 == 0 }
n = 3
case n
when even
  puts "even!"
else
  puts "odd!"
end
```

It works because the `case/when` is basically executed like this:

```
if even === n
  puts "even!"
else
  puts "odd!"
end
```

The `case/when` checks which branch to execute by calling `===` on the arguments to `when` clauses, picking the first that returns a truthy value.

Despite its similarity to the equality operator (`==`) it not a stronger or weaker form of it. I try to think of the `===` operator as the "belongs to" operator. `Class` defines it so that you can check if an object *belongs to* the class (i.e. is an instance of the class or a subclass of the class), `Range` defines it as to check if the argument *belongs to* the range (i.e. is included in the range), and so on. This doesn't really make the `Proc` case make more sense, but think of it as a tool for making your own *belongs to* operators, like my example above; I defined an object that can determine if something *belongs to* the set of even numbers.

Comment: Oh the lengths to which ruby goes in order to have nice case/when blocks :-) `String === "foo" => true`

Answer (score 5):

Note that `===` in Ruby is NOT about equality, unlike JavaScript. It is specifically used [for case expressions](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#caseexpressions):

```
case cats.length
  when 42                         # Uses 42      === cats.length
    puts :uh
  when /cool/i                    # Uses /cool/i === cats.length
    puts :oh
  when ->(n){ n.odd? || n/3==6 }  # Passes cats.length to the proc
    puts :my
end
```

Comment: @louism No more odd, IMO, than using regex in a case statement (the equivalent of Enumerable#grep) or than using a block for `Enumerable#select`.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is useful in case construction, when you need to calculate something at the comparing.

```
is_odd  =-> n { n%2 != 0 }
is_even =-> n { n%2 == 0 }

case 5
when is_even
  puts "the number is even"
when is_odd
  puts "the number is odd"
end

=> the number is odd
```

Comment: Hmm... i made my edit before @theo added something similar to his answer... GMTA

Comment: @John Bachir, I don't think that your edit is good to describe the idea of lambda in case construction

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have any relationship to the normal meaning of === (asking if the two objects are the same object)?

Actually, that's a common misconception about `===` in Ruby. It's actually not strictly for `Object#object_id` comparison (although that is its behavior in many common invocations). In Ruby, `===` is case [subsumption](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subsume).

Here's the description of `===` from `Object`: "Case Equality -- For class Object, effectively the same
as calling  #==, but typically overridden by descendants
to provide meaningful semantics in case statements."

Sadly, even though it is comprised of three `=`, it doesn't have anything even remotely to do with equality :-D